# Cell joining, bracketing, and rounding in one excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to combine three functions in one formula that will achieve the following:

- Join columns C & D
- Put parentheses () around column D value
- Round column D to one decimal place

I can successfully join columns and parenthesize column D using =C8&"("&D8&")"
However, this results in the value from column D showing all four decimal places, despite viewing only one decimal place in column D.

To resolve this, I amended the formula to: =C7&ROUND(("("&D7&")"), 1)
However, the parentheses disappear and there is now a dash between the values of column C&D.

Is there a different syntax that will permit me to also keep parentheses using only one formula, or will I have to do an additional transformation step before joining columns?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, the parenthesis have to be around the rounded value:

```
=C7&"("&ROUND(D7, 1)&")"
```

Comment: Brilliant - that worked.  Thank you so much.